# How to merge two different collections with functional style?

Tags: scala, list, collections, functional-programming

I have two collections:

```
val one = Seq(("1", 123), ("3", 555), ("2", 31))

val two = Seq("1", "4", "2")
```

I need to append second seq to first (order doesn't matter), example:

```
val result = Seq(("1", 123), ("2", 31), ("3", 555), ("4", 0)) //0 - constant
```

I can make it with transforming to set and iteration with contains check, but it's very ugly. How to implement this with correct "functional" style?

Comment: I can't understand how you concatenate your sequences in the example above. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible ways. One of them is:

```
val oneKeys = one.map(_._1)
val result = one ++ two.filterNot(x => oneKeys.contains(x)).map(x => (x,0))
```

The expanation of methods:

```
val oneKeys = one.map(_._1) //gets the keys of each tuple from list `one`
two.filterNot(x => oneKeys.contains(x))  //selects the keys that list `one` does not contain
   .map(x => (x,0))                            //converts them into tuples by adding value `0`
```

`++` operation basically merges two different `Seq` and returns the result

Comment: This does `one.map(_._1)` (creating a new `Seq`) for each element of `two`. Not great for performance.

Comment: You are right. I am editing my solution according to your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what would be correct "functional" style. However, you can easily append these two collections together by using `Map`.

```
val result = (two.map((_,0)).toMap ++ one).toSeq
```

First all values in the `two` collection will be added with a value 0. The the `one` collection will be added, this will overwrite the values in the `Map` where the key is the same. After this you can simply convert the `Map` to a `Seq` which will give the desired result.